# How to create Map<String,Int> from a number of Objects containing a Name and a List

Tags: java, java-stream

So I have 3 University Instances each having a String Name  and a List of Courses:

[this is univerities.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExNrA.png)

I want to create a map with the names of the Universities as the keys and the value should be the number of courses. I tried this using a stream pipeline:

```
   Map<String,Int> result = universities.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(University::getName,University::getCourses.size()))
```

[And it doesnt work because you probably cant use such methods on Lists right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWgST.png)

My guess is that  could use these methods on ArrayLists, but I am a bit lost how to pull that of in a stream Pipeline since this is still new to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to write out the lambda: `u -> u.getCourses().size()`.

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as images.

Comment: You probably mean `Integer`, as there is no type `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I avoid Collectors because they are complicated and unnecessary. Without Collectors, you could do the following:

```
List<Universities> universities = //...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Integer> result = Map.ofEntries(universities.stream()
                                  .map(university -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(university.getName(), university.getCourses().size()))
                                  .toArray(Map.Entry[]::new));
```

If you really want to use Collectors, this is what you're looking for:

```
List<Universities> universities = //...
Map<String, Integer> result = universities.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                  University::getName,
                                  university -> university.getCourses().size()
                              ));
```

The following is with regards to the `Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper` (2nd parameter) of `Collectors.toMap(...)`:

`List#size()` is a function call, not a reference to the size function pointer. `List::size` is closer to what you are looking for (using "::" for reference to function pointer). Notice that you put `University::getCourses`, which returns the function pointer for the `University#getCourses()` method, not a `List`. The `University#getCourses()` method does not execute until the `Stream#collect(...)` method calls `valueMapper.apply(...)`. Since there is no single method call to map a `University` to the length of its courses, I believe there is no way to accomplish this task with just function pointers, so just use the above lambda.